Tilting due to Earth's rotation at a distance
I just stumbled upon a video on spacetime and a weird fact caught my attention.

In the video, it explained that a free falling body dropped onto the Earth would change its orientation and would be displaced very little due to the rotation of the Earth.

Why would this happen? It may be different in Einstein's gravitational relativity theory however in classical physics shouldn't it simply fall (without any atmosphere)?
Clip of the video :https://youtube.com/clip/UgkxQN4DFgqDB6dsb4vPT2Ireqh9J7rW4gzP?si=7XlLZEiVljm6ObQe

That video is specifically about the properties of gravitational interaction in terms of General Relativity. Now, in that video the narration assumes it will be obvious to the viewer that the video is not about classical dynamics. The title of the whole video is: "What if we could see spacetime?" The expression 'spacetime' is used only in the context of relativistic physics. So the author of that video figured: if it says 'spacetime' in the title the visitors will understand that the video is about General Relativity, not about classical mechanics.

You might start with another Science Clic video - What is General Relativity?, The phenomenon you are asking about is called Frame Dragging. A lot of sources talk about it, but I don't know of one that gives a simple explanation of why. You might look at this - We know there is no aether, so what is being dragged in frame dragging?

If you stand on a high tower, the velocity on the top is greater, than at the bottom, since the angular velocity is the same. So if you drop a stone it has compared to the bottom a relativ velocity parallel to earth surface , thats why it will not fall down vertically but drift a very little in the direction of earth rotation. I don't think the video explaining is is good.

That video clip is specifically for the case where an object that has no angular velocity is released from height, gravitationally attracted to a planet beneath it. What you are discussing is the case where an object that is initially co-rotating with the Earth is released from height.

@Cleonis Yep exactly. With a tower its quite obvious. However with a free falling body with no angular velocity dropped straight down should not tilt or rotate.

If you look from the perspective of someone on earth who considers himself not moving, the apple drift against   earth movement. I think thats what the movie wants to  tell.
